# mysql or sqlite and safety of design choice

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, database-design, data-structures

I am developing a inventory program where each user will have unique privileges based on what the owner of the company decided to assign each employee. At first I was just creating a php file to see if a given user was allowed on a page but this can quickly get to big to manage.

Then I created user groups and managed them though php as well. But this got to big to manage as well. Now I am thinking it may be better to create a "Master" permissions table in my database and just have the permissions per page be decided off of this.

Or perhaps just have an sqlite db it runs off. This program will never see the interweb and will always be hidden behind the vail of a VPN. even so would this be a safe approach? and is it scaleable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical way of handling permissions... If you have a simple system you can check a page (URL) against a particular permission (Does Bob have permission to view Widgets?) but when you're dealing with more complex systems that approach is inadequate. For instance, maybe everyone can view a page of employees but only HR administrators can see employee addresses and only payroll admins can see the social security number.

A role-based approach allows you to have an unlimited number of roles with whatever actions they need and you can give each user an unlimited number of roles.

We need a table that defines all actions that require special permission.

```
actions
    id              varchar(50)(P)
    description     text

+---------------+---------------------------+
| id            | description               |
+---------------+---------------------------+
| widget_add    | Add widgets               |
| widget_delete | Delete widgets            |
| widget_update | Update widget information |
| widget_view   | View widget information   |
| ............. | ......................... |
+---------------+---------------------------+
```

We also need to describe various roles our users can have. My example data shows we have an Administrator of Widgets, a Clerk who works in the Widget department and an Accountant.

```
roles
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(25)

+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Widget Admin |
|  2 | Widget Clerk |
|  3 | Accountant   |
| .. | ............ |
+----+--------------+
```

Now we associate a role with the actions it can perform. My example data shows that role 1 (the Widget Administrator) can add, delete, update and view widget information while role 2 (the Widget Clerk) can only add, update and view Widgets. Finally, the Accountant can only view widgets.

```
roles_actions
    role_id             unsigned int \_ (P) (F roles.id)
    action_id           varchar(50)  /      (F actions.id)

+---------+---------------+
| role_id | action_id     |
+---------+---------------+
|       1 | widget_add    |
|       1 | widget_delete |
|       1 | widget_update |
|       1 | widget_view   |
|       2 | widget_add    |
|       2 | widget_update |
|       2 | widget_view   |
|       3 | widget_view   |
| ....... | ............. |
+---------+---------------+
```

And of course we have our users (with their typical super-secure passwords).

```
users
    id                      unsigned int(P)
    username                varchar(64)
    password                varbinary(255)
    name                    varchar(255)

+----+----------+----------+-------+
| id | username | password | name  |
+----+----------+----------+-------+
|  1 | bob      | bob123   | Bob   |
|  2 | mary     | mary789  | Mary  |
|  3 | kelly    | kellyxxx | Kelly |
| .. | ........ | ........ | ..... |
+----+----------+----------+-------+
```

Now you associate users with their roles. Bob is an Accountant, Mary is a Widget Admin and Kelly is a Widget Clerk. So Bob can view widget information, Mary can add/update/delete/view widget information and Kelly and add/update/view widget data.

```
users_roles
    user_id         unsigned int \_ (P) (F users.id)
    role_id         unsigned int /      (F roles.id)

+---------+---------+
| user_id | role_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       3 |
|       2 |       1 |
|       3 |       2 |
| ....... | ....... |
+---------+---------+
```